# XElement adds an xmlns

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I'm using Linq to XML to create a new XML file. Some part of the file do I get from an existing XML file. I use the following code for this.

```
var v2 = new XDocument(
  new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", ""),
  new XComment(string.Format("Converted from version 1. Date: {0}", DateTime.Now)),
  new XElement(ns + "keyem",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", xsd.NamespaceName),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName),
    new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemaLocation.NamespaceName),
    new XAttribute("version", "2"),
    new XAttribute("description", description),
    new XElement(ns + "layout",
      new XAttribute("type", type),
      new XAttribute("height", height),
      new XAttribute("width", width),
      settings.Root)       // XML from an existing file
```

The problem is that it adds xmlns = "" the first element from the existing file.

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<foo 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd KeyEmFileSchema.xsd"
  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd">
  <settings xmlns="">
      ...
  </settings>
</foo>
```

The XML file I'm reading from looks like this, but I can change it if needed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<settings>
  <colormaps>
    <colormap color="Gray"     textcolor="Black"/>
    <colormap color="DarkGray" textcolor="White"/>
    <colormap color="Black"    textcolor="White"/>
    <colormap color="Cyan"     textcolor="Black"/>
  </colormaps>
  <macromaps>
    <macromap pattern="^@([0-9A-F]{2})\|([0-9A-F]{2})$"  replace="{ESC}$1{ESC}$2{MOUSERESET}"/>
    <macromap pattern="^\$([0-9A-F]{2})\|([0-9A-F]{2})$" replace="{USERCLICK}{ESC}$1{ESC}$2{MOUSERESET}"/>
    <macromap pattern="^\$([0-9A-F]{2})$"                replace="{USERCLICK}{ESC}$1"/>
  </macromaps>
  <keydefault color="Cyan"/>
  <groupdefault color="DarkGray"/>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're seeing this because the settings element (presumably coming from your document) does not live in this namespace. It lives in the default/null-uri namespace.

You would need to transform your input document in order to change it's namespace.

This somewhat simplified example take your xml file and places it into another document but, before it does so, it changes the namespace of every element in that xml file to that of your target document...

```
    static void ProcessXmlFile()
    {
        XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd/";

        // load the xml document
        XElement settings = XElement.Load("data.xml");

        // shift ALL elements in the settings document into the target namespace
        foreach (XElement e in settings.DescendantsAndSelf())
        {
            e.Name = ns + e.Name.LocalName;
        }

        // write the output document
        var file = new XDocument(new XElement(ns + "foo",
                                        settings));

        Console.Write(file.ToString());            
    }
```

The result of which this...

```
<foo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/KeyEmFileSchema.xsd/">
  <settings>
    <colormaps>
      <colormap color="Gray" textcolor="Black" />
      <colormap color="DarkGray" textcolor="White" />
      <colormap color="Black" textcolor="White" />
      <colormap color="Cyan" textcolor="Black" />
    </colormaps>
    <macromaps>
      <macromap pattern="^@([0-9A-F]{2})\|([0-9A-F]{2})$" replace="{ESC}$1{ESC}$2{MOUSERESET}" />
      <macromap pattern="^\$([0-9A-F]{2})\|([0-9A-F]{2})$" replace="{USERCLICK}{ESC}$1{ESC}$2{MOUSERESET}" />
      <macromap pattern="^\$([0-9A-F]{2})$" replace="{USERCLICK}{ESC}$1" />
    </macromaps>
    <keydefault color="Cyan" />
    <groupdefault color="DarkGray" />
  </settings>
</foo>
```

As you can see, the settings element is now in the same namespace as the foo element. This is essentially a quick and dirty xml transform, and clearly it doesn't respect any namespaces in the xml doc you're importing. But this might be what you're after, or might at least form the basis of something more robust.

Comment: I understand that, but how do I do that?
I've tried defaultSettings.Name = ns+ defaultSettings.Name.LocalName;
But I must do it for all sub-elements. Must be something better.

Comment: You either need to transform the document using Xslt techniques, or read each element in and transform it in code. Basically, the XDocument you've loaded knows the namespace of each element in that doc, and know that it's not the same namespace as foo.

Comment: Can I change the xml file I read from to get it to be in the right namepsace?

Comment: Do you have a snippet/sample of your settings xml?

Comment: Also, your code example doesn't compile. Have you removed some aspect of it? The 2nd line doesn't look right.

Comment: @magol Would I be right in thinking that you don't care about the namespaces of the xml file? You just want those elements to appear inline with your output doc, in the namespace of that output doc?

Comment: @Martin Peck - This is exactly what I was after. I managed to solve it before you responded by recursive go through all elements, but to use DescendantsAndSelf was much smarter. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

You could write an extension method for this.
This method has a return value so it supports chaining, but also changes transformation of the original so it can be used without assignment.

```
public static XElement EnsureNamespaceExists(this XElement xElement, XNamespace xNamespace)
{
    string nodeName = xElement.Name.LocalName;

    if (!xElement.HasAttribute("xmlns"))
    {
        foreach (XElement tmpElement in xElement.DescendantsAndSelf())
        {
            tmpElement.Name = xNamespace + tmpElement.Name.LocalName;
        }
        xElement = new XElement(xNamespace + nodeName, xElement.FirstNode);
    }

    return xElement;
}
```